International Air Travel: Can I bring several hair care products in check in luggage?
I am travelling from Bangalore, India to Bordeaux, France through Air France. I am not sure how much quantity of shampoo, hair serum, conditioner etc I can carry in my checked in luggage? Is there any limit on per bottle or altogether quantity!

The quantities are not nearly as small as for cabin luggage but there are some limits. Air France's website states that

The net total of all toiletries, non-radioactive medication, and aerosol products cited above is limited to 2 kg/4.4 lbs. or 2 L/67.6 oz per person. The net quantity of each item must not exceed 0.5 kg/1.1 lb. or 500 ml/16.9 oz.

The airline won't be concerned with that but there is also a €430 limit on the value of the goods you are allowed to import tax-free in France / the EU. You could easily exceed that with some cosmetics products (fragrances, make-up), not sure about hair care products. If the products you want to take with you are worth more than €430 in total, you are still allowed to import them but you are supposed to go through the red channel and pay some VAT and customs duty.
This doesn't cover all liquids but specifically toiletries as there are separate rules for alcoholic beverages.

ok got your point.... but if its below 430 euro then all ok right? also the weight or volume is below 2 liter (to be exact it is going to apprx. 650 ml of hair conditioner, hair serum. cleanser ) so it will be all ok?

@Aeries_firebug Yes, I see no reason why it would be a problem in this case.

FWIW, I had my checked luggage pulled aside and inspected because of about 1 liter of liquid. I was called in because they couldn't understand what it was, otherwise I might never have known about it. So it will, at least, increase the chances someone will be pawing through your stuff.

Last month I took 4.5L soft drinks/soda, plus various toiletries from Denmark to the UK with no issues at all. I don't think it'd present an issue provided they're at least factory-labelled.

@DavidWheatley That's a different question, though. Air France says 5L for alcoholic drinks. I saw nothing about soft drinks so it would make sense to be allowed to take at least as much or possibly as much as your weight allowance permits. This also fits Spehro's story: The concern is presumably the composition of the product, not the amount of liquids per se. I also imagine that, unlike cabin luggage rules, these rules may be somewhat airline specific and not necessarily enforced systematically.
